# How to make a pointed color bar for an image plot - R

Tags: r, image, plot, colors, legend

I have a precipitation field over South America that ranges from 0 to 70. I'm only interested in values between 0 and 12, so I want to plot the field in this range, with values >12 in the extreme color, and I want the color bar legend to have a pointed end, indicating that every value greater than 12 is in that color, something like this:

[Example with the color bar the way I want it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtOLm.jpg)

Does anyone knows how to do this? So far I haven't found a way to make any other than a rectangular color bar.

Comment: I'd suggest you show us how you would have done it with ordinary color bars... with a working example. Then mods could be proposed and tested.

Comment: I meant that when using `image.plot()`, for example, it automatically creates a rectangular color bar.

Comment: `?image.plot` returns: "No documentation for ‘image.plot’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??image.plot’" (Also not sure why you are responding to this comment. Appears you have an answer.)

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to write your own custom color bar plotting function implemented with primitive drawing functions like [`rect()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/rect.html), [`polygon()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/polygon.html), and [`text()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/text.html). For example:

```
arrowedColorBar <- function(ylow,yhigh,xcenter,xwidth,nums,...,cols=rainbow(length(nums)+2L)) {
    x1 <- xcenter-xwidth/2;
    x2 <- xcenter+xwidth/2;
    ys <- seq(ylow,yhigh,len=length(nums)+2L);
    y1 <- ys[1L];
    y2 <- ys[2L];
    polygon(c(x1,xcenter,x2),c(y2,y1,y2),col=cols[1L]);
    for (i in seq_along(nums)) {
        y1 <- ys[i+1L];
        y2 <- ys[i+2L];
        if (i<length(nums)) rect(x1,y1,x2,y2,col=cols[i+1L]);
        text(x2,y1,nums[i],pos=4L,...);
    }; ## end for
    y1 <- ys[length(ys)-1L];
    y2 <- ys[length(ys)];
    polygon(c(x1,xcenter,x2),c(y1,y2,y1),col=cols[length(cols)]);
    invisible();
}; ## end arrowedColorBar()

plot(c(-80,-40),c(-60,20),pch=NA,xlab='x',ylab='y');
arrowedColorBar(-60,10,-45,1.3,c(1,2,3,4,5,7,10,13,15),font=2L);
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! I will try this and let you know.